# How to use different colors in group of text in turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want to display text by using `turtle.write()`.

Here is my code so far:

```
import turtle

window = turtle.Screen()
 
turtle.screensize(500,500)
turtle.bgcolor("white")

score_1 = 0
score_2 = 0
score = turtle.Turtle()
score.penup()
score.hideturtle()
score.speed(0)
score.goto(0,150)
score.color("red")
score.write("Team1: {} Team2: {}".format(score_1, score_1), align='center', font=("courier",20,"bold"))
```

The whole line of text is red while I want the text `Team1:  Team2:` to be red and `score_1  score_2` to be blue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want in this situation is the `move=True` argument to the turtle `write()` method.  Normally, writing doesn't affect the turtle's position but in this case, where we're piecing together text out of small segments, we want the turtle to move as we write:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

FONT = ("courier", 20, "bold")

screen = Screen()
screen.screensize(500, 500)

score_1 = 20
score_2 = 13

score = Turtle()
score.hideturtle()
score.speed('fastest')
score.penup()
score.sety(150)

# repeat, after score.clear(), every time we update score
score.setx(-114)  # estimated
score.color("red")
score.write("Team1: ", move=True, font=FONT)
score.color("blue")
score.write(score_1, move=True, font=FONT)
score.color("red")
score.write(" Team2: ", move=True, font=FONT)
score.color("blue")
score.write(score_2, move=True, font=FONT)

screen.mainloop()
```

The `move=True` on the final `write()` isn't strictly necessary but it's useful if we want to print out the `xcor()` of the turtle after writing to determine how wide our line is in pixels.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ever see those clicky-pens with multiple colors in them?  Click it, get a new color?  Pretty much the same thing here, just pick a color & draw.  Also your formatting is off;  put **four spaces** in front of each line in your script.

```
score.color('red')
score.write( f'Team1: {score_1}' )

score.color('blue')
score.write( f'Team2: {score_2}')
```

---

**Edit:**  Same diff.

```
score.color('red')
score.write('Team1: ')

score.color('blue')
score.write( f'{score_1}')

score.color('red')
score.write('Team2: ')

score.color('blue')
score.write( f'{score_2}')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. as you way, Team1 and score_1 are in red and Team2 and score_2 are in blue but the thing here is I want Team1 and Team2 are red while score_1, score_2 are in blue.

Comment: Yup, fix your formatting.  Put **4 spaces in front of each line** of your app.

Comment: Thanks again. Can you help me to write the whole coding to show up those texts in the same line. The out put is: Team1: score_1  Team2: score_2.

Comment: I got the result as I want with you help but it took me 24 lines of code